# Does a UDP connection require a server/client?

Tags: java, android, networking, server, udp

I want to send out a UDP packet/message out to another device on the same ethernet connection, but I'm not sure where a server/client relationship would be here.

The receiving message is configured to automatically send a response back upon receiving a message, so both devices would just be communicating to each other...

Am I missing something?

I'm confused because the code I used to send a message from a client to a server has parameters "server ip" and "server port" so I'm not sure if I can 1) just replace the parameters and use the same code and 2) if it's possible, what to put in those parameters, the initial device's port # and ip? Or the second device's?

Thanks!

The code snippet:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        InetAddress SERVERIP = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);
                        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
                        socket.setBroadcast(true);
                        byte[] msg = message.getBytes();
                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(msg, message.length(), 
                                SERVERIP, SERVERPORT);
                        socket.send(packet);
                        socket.close();
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
```

Comment: You could replace the phrase "client" with "source" and "server" with "destination" of a connection.

Comment: So I should replace the ServerIP and ServerPort with the ip and port of my destination? @SteffenUllrich

Comment: UDP is explicitly _connectionless_,, so there is no such thing as a UDP connection. Also, client/server is an application-layer concept that UDP knows nothing about. UDP does not have clients or servers. UDP is a fire-and-forget protocol that just sends datagrams with no expectation that the other side even receives the datagrams.

Comment: @RonMaupin: yes and no. While there is no "real" connection like in TCP with a dedicated connection start (SYN etc) and connection end (FIN etc), a number of packets from the same source ip+port to the same destination ip+port are typically considered a connection. Such connections also have explicit support in NAT and the `connect` functions is also available for UDP sockets. And there is client/server in UDP too, like a DNS server, web server implementing the QUIC protocol (which is UDP) etc. In general client and server is a concept from the application layer anyway.

Comment: @qol: "So I should replace the ServerIP and ServerPort with the ip and port of my destination?" - correct.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich "_a number of packets from the same source ip+port to the same destination ip+port are typically considered a connection._" Not from the perspective of UDP, which does not even care than any of sent the datagrams are even received by the destination. "_the `connect` functions is also available for UDP sockets._" That, too, is an application-layer concept. Applications and application-layer protocols can create connections using UDP, but UDP does not have connections. As far as NAT goes, it has to guess when the conversation using UDP is over because there is no UDP connection.

Comment: @RonMaupin: That's true - while TCP by itself has the concept of a connection with UDP this concepts only comes from the application layer. This means that the concept of connections is possible with UDP but is not intrinsic to UDP like it is with TCP. Still the concept of a connection over UDP (which is not exactly the same as a UDP connection though) is still common so that NAT systems explicitly support it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, but then it is an application or application-layer protocol connection, not a UDP connection, even if it uses UDP. I think the language around it often confuses people that really do not understand how UDP works. I just see that here all too often, and then the OP was worried about client/server for UDP, but that has nothing to do with UDP either. However the application is created determines if there are clients/servers or peers, and UDP, TCP, or any other transport protocol is besides the point of that question, and not at all an important point of the question.

Comment: @RonMaupin: You are right. But the concept of what is transport layer and what is application layer and where the concept of connection and client-server fits in is likely not clear for the OP. The OP clearly describes an application protocol (one device send a message, the other sends a response) which is fundamentally a client-server relationship implemented with UDP. Understanding the difference between UDP connection (transport layer) and UDP based connection (application layer) requires an understanding of the different abstraction layers first.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, yes, which is why I made the comment. Network programming is much, much easier if you understand the network concepts, including the network stack layers, and the idea of abstraction and encapsulation behind the layers, before trying to use the network APIs.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich My code isn't working after replacing the server's info with the destinations... is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @qol: There is not enough code to actually have something to reproduce. But the `setBroadcast` makes no sense since you are not broadcasting anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if the question you want answered is how to respond to the device that sent the message from the device that received the message.

If this is the case then the following code is a basic example of how you could respond to the initial sender device by getting the address and port from the packet that was received over the socket.

```
// Receive and respond thread.
new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // Receive

                        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(4445);
                        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                        socket.receive(packet);

                        // Respond

                        // Get sender's/return address from the packet that was received.
                        InetAddress address = packet.getAddress();
                        // Get sender's/return port from the packet that was received.
                        int port = packet.getPort();
                        packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
                        socket.send(packet);
                        socket.close();

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

I would also recommend reading the following [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html#:%7E:text=The%20example%20featured%20in%20this,client%20request%20for%20a%20quotation.) regarding writing a datagram server and client.